# Why do I see Failed to fetch error while dping apt-get update

Tags: docker, apt, http-error

apt-get update in my jenkins job fails wth Http404 error on pulling docker hub related repositiories

```
12:38:54 + uname -a
12:38:54 Linux c612ce175fe3 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
12:28:18 W: Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404
12:28:18 
12:28:18 W: Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  HttpError404
12:28:18
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have the same problem on several older Ubuntu test systems.  Finally found this notice when searching the URL with the 404 error https://apt.dockerproject.org/

> Notice: Shutting down dockerproject.org APT and YUM repos 2020-03-31
>
> Docker will be shutting down the deprecated APT and YUM repositories hosted at "dockerproject.org" and "dockerproject.com" on the 31st of March 2020.
>
> We noticed that this project is referencing one of these repositories, and recommend updating to use the "download.docker.com" repository to prevent disruption.
>
> More info: https://www.docker.com/blog/changes-dockerproject-org-apt-yum-repositories/

My fix was to edit either /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list or /etc/apt/sources.list and comment out the old line and add a new the new line.  For my raspberry pi I used [arch=armhf] instead of [arch=amd64], hope this helps.

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

make this change

```
#       deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu trusty stable
```

Comment: This fixed the `Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Could not resolve host: apt.dockerproject.org` error, for me (for `sudo apt-get update`). Thanks. I did need to run `y-ppa-manager` to fix one subsequent issue.

Comment: I also had to re-add the GPG key after updating the sources list with `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -` - https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Answer (score 1):

I faced on same issue.
But I made a following change in `docker.list` file.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

and made a following change.

```
# deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main
```

And then,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It did work for me.
Thank you.